# Enforce type specification on public members of Groovy types

Tags: eclipse, groovy, conventions, checkstyle, type-safety

In Groovy, specifying types is optional. But there are advantages to specifying them on public class members like methods and properties. It's a good form of documentation and it enables IDEs to perform auto-completion, refactor code, find references, and other static analysis tasks more reliably as described in this [Groovy Coding Style](http://java.dzone.com/articles/groovy-coding-style) article.

Is there a way to enforce this policy in Eclipse so that a warning will appear when a public member is missing an explicit type? Something along the lines of a [Checkstyle](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/) or [FindBugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/) tool for Groovy would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is nothing like this in Groovy-Eclipse at the moment, but this is an interesting idea.  You can raise an enhancement request for this:

http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRECLIPSE

Answer (score 1):

Just as a comment, the standard tool for groovy static analysis is [codenarc](http://codenarc.sourceforge.net/). Don't know if the rule you mentioned is there, but it has a lot of options and it is continuously improving.
Regarding your question about eclipse support, I believe there is nothing like that yet.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, but I couldn't find such a rule in their suite.